# GA // Tracking onClick Events via a Class that generates unique output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Below is the code I keep trying; I'm basically just trying to use this to track the page with General GA; then assign a class that tracks onClick events within a category and generates a 1,2,3 automatically at the end of the file name. I'm essentially just trying to streamline tracking my onClick files within a website; I do not want to continue manually adding onClick code to every file I'm trying to track on a page. **What is the matter with my below code?**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35609953-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'JPG', '/downloads/img/LowRes01.jpg']);


  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

<!-- GA track all onClicks -->

<script>
$(function(){
    $('.downloadsmall a').attr("onclick", function(i){
        var x='LowRes0'+(i+1)+'.jpg';
        return "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/downloads/img/"+x+"'])";
        return "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'JPG', '/downloads/img/"+x+"'])";

    });
});​
</script>

<!-- End GA track all onClicks -->

<style>

#wrap {
    width: 940px;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
}

#left {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#right {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

.downloadsmall {
height: 50px;
width: 200px;
border: 3px dotted #333;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrap"><!-- Wrap -->

    <div id="left">

<p class="downloadsmall">
    download: <a href="http://www.google.com">Low Res</a>
</p>

    </div>

  <div id="right">

<p class="downloadsmall">
    download: <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Low Res</a>
</p>

    </div>
    </div><!-- Wrap -->
```

**UPDATED ----**

*Below is the code updated per Jasper's Response; (thanks !) I have it in and am awaiting to see how it resolves.*

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- GA track all onClicks -->

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35609953-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'JPG', '/downloads/img/"+x+"']);


$(function(){
    $('.downloadsmall a').on("click", function(){
        var theHREF = $(this).attr('href'),
            myGAQ   = _gaq || [];
        myGAQ.push(['_trackPageview', theHREF]);
        myGAQ.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'JPG', theHREF]);

    });
});

</script>

<!-- End GA track all onClicks -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a string from your event handler, which won't actually do anything. Instead, just run the code normally. Also, once you `return` something from a function, the function stops executing, so your second `return` isn't even being run.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.downloadsmall a').on("click", function(i){
        var x     = 'LowRes0'+(i+1)+'.jpg',
            myGAQ = _gaq || [];
        myGAQ.push(['_trackPageview', '/downloads/img/' + x]);
        myGAQ.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'JPG', '/downloads/img/' + x]);

    });
});​
```

This code is actually accessing the GA `_gaq` object and asking it to create a page-view and an event tracking beacon.

The code still shouldn't work though, as the `i` argument in your event handler is really the `event` object, not an index (which I'm assuming is what you want). You could get the actual HREF of the link and use it as your tracking data:

```
$(function(){
    $('.downloadsmall a').on("click", function(){
        var theHREF = $(this).attr('href'),
            myGAQ   = _gaq || [];
        myGAQ.push(['_trackPageview', theHREF]);
        myGAQ.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'JPG', theHREF]);

    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks - Just updated my Q; I put what you wrote in; and am going to test it !